# How to include multiple paths into vxworks ftp server

Tags: ftp, vxworks

I am working around a vxworks project. The pc had been installed  two os, winxp and vxworks. Usually I update the vxworks img by restarting the pc into WinXP and copy the vxworks img to one dir, such like root dir of disk c, and reboot the pc into dos. Startup script in dos will hload the 'vxworks ' file  and make the  vxworks running.
        `Ftpserver` component in vxworks is an useful utility. I can config it to mount disk d, which is the data disk. And I want that it also contains disk c,which contains img. By doing so, I could update vxworks img while it is running. And no need to reboot into `WinXP`. How to make it?

And there are two components `Ftp` and `TFTP`, what is  the difference.
`FTPS_INITIAL_DIR`, `FTPS_ROOT_DIR`,`TFTPS_DIR`, how to config to make them work smoothly.

Comment: I found that disk path is named in different manner. Such as ata0a,ata0b and so on. Other may be named like ahci00:1,ahci00:2 and so on. I found some posts figure out that different file system has different style. Like hrfs,rawfs,dosfs and something seems like that  pattern. Is there any experts to make all these questions solved by one stop?

Comment: How  to  get the value of 'IPCOM_FILE_ROOT'. This macro is used frequently. But I didn't find the defination .